# Using composer with php in non standard location

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to use composer on my NAS (a good old D-Link DNS-323 running the incredibly good fonz fun plug 0.7).

I have my php installed in `/ffp/bin/php`.

When I install composer using the following command

```
 php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/ffp/sbin --filename=composer
```

But when I do a simple `less /ffp/sbin/composer`, I have the following shebang set :

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of Composer.
 *
```

Unfortunatly, my NAS do not have the `/usr/bin/env` folder existing on my machine ...
So, how can I have composer referring to the correct php executable ?

Besides, I tried changing the declaration to use `#!/ffp/bin/php`, but when doing so, any composer run echoes the following result :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/ffp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/gd.so' - File not found in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/ffp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/gd.so' - File not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/ffp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/sqlite.so' - File not found in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/ffp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/sqlite.so' - File not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar "/mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer" has a broken signature' in /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer:23
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer on line 23
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar "/mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer" has a broken signature' in /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer:23
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer on line 23
```

Of particular importance is the line

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar "/mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer" has a broken signature' in /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/sbin/composer:23
```

How can i fix it ? In other words, how can I have a working php + composer installation on my NAS ?

Comment: just call it with php! /ffp/bin/php /ffp/sbin/composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, how can I have composer referring to the correct php executable ?

A very simple solution is to create a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/ffp/bin/php -n /ffp/sbin/composer "$@"
```

Make it executable, name it `composer`, put it in your path before `/ffp/sbin` (or rename `/ffp/sbin/composer` to `composer.phar` and update the above script too).

The `-n` flag tells PHP to not use `php.ini`. This is useful when there are many extensions loaded from `php.ini`; not loading them makes `composer` run faster. Especially `xdebug` is [recommended to **not** be loaded](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer) by `composer`, for speed improvement.